# Multiple aggregation in order on one data frame or using data.table

Tags: r, aggregation

I'm trying to aggregate the following colums

```
"Module" "Timestamp" "SessionName" "MinutesDelivered" "UserName" "ViewingType" "TimestampDate"
```

So I'm trying to get totals for above in a certain order with combinations of columns.

Essentially occurrences of the username using a particular session name on a particular date.

So for example "Johhny" logs in on the 5-12-2018 for 3 sessions on Culture  and "Mary" logs in on the 5-15-2018 for 5 sessions on Repetitive Strain Injury

I'm wondering if there is a function in R that would do this I've looked at plyr::ddply, plyr::count, and aggregate in base R. However I wondering if my approach is wrong, should I break them out into separate tables for each session/date/user or is there a way to do this in data.tables?

dput() below

```
structure(list(Module = c("LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", 
"LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", 
"LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", 
"LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", 
"LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", 
"LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", 
"LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", 
"LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316", "LW3316"), Timestamp = structure(c(1505150699, 
1505151162, 1505152271, 1505162284, 1505220287, 1505220576, 1505243735, 
1505314660, 1505329575, 1505333453, 1505409497, 1505653851, 1505673294, 
1505682757, 1505723994, 1505735318, 1506000530, 1506000945, 1506007655, 
1506026131, 1506026495, 1506027981, 1506085966, 1506209482, 1506256877, 
1506277180, 1506280734, 1506340129, 1506351107, 1506938483, 1506949182, 
1506949619, 1506949637, 1506954271, 1507389553, 1507389554, 1507390707, 
1507480298, 1507636241, 1507667557, 1507808686, 1507818563, 1507841392, 
1508366237, 1508368180, 1508508172, 1508513010, 1508513049, 1508513340, 
1508513362), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    SessionName = c("LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/18/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/18/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/18/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/18/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/11/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/25/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/25/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/18/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/18/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/18/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/25/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 10/2/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 10/2/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/25/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 9/25/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 9/25/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 10/9/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 10/9/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 10/9/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 10/9/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 10/9/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 on 10/2/2017 (Mon)", 
    "LW3316 on 10/2/2017 (Mon)", "LW3316 20 October 2017 at 12:02:21", 
    "20 October 2017 at 12:48:25", "20 October 2017 at 14:28:43", 
    "LW3316 20 October 2017 at 12:02:21", "20 October 2017 at 12:48:25"
    ), MinutesDelivered = c(4.87966666666664, 1.75285, 1.20426666666667, 
    28.9991920666666, 4.25249816666662, 0.0704192166666667, 0.407210766666667, 
    5.45169568333334, 104.33214055, 21.53249713645, 8.00026251666665, 
    32.8035570268167, 97.0560580999999, 11.927976873, 0.842423333333264, 
    3.34293333333328, 32.6008951666667, 23.5674802833333, 72.0751911099997, 
    0.05312915, 13.0953792166667, 21.0956275666667, 110.812050533333, 
    0.582068705000057, 97.5797333333343, 39.5602278700001, 3.98265503333316, 
    3.06983356666667, 30.5694796, 0.0196552166666682, 5.00846043333334, 
    0.1166757, 1.15660625, 3.16763836666668, 13.6891576166668, 
    4.8705137, 0.118677966666655, 69.3671006786945, 2.16981438333333, 
    73.6285150499999, 30.0131027666667, 0.0219079938666667, 65.7004652833333, 
    0.292117699999998, 7.36973023333333, 1.59354231666667, 0.410658333333335, 
    0.981110616666665, 0.179261400000001, 1.24121838333333), 
    UserName = c("Celestina  ", "Milo  ", "Marian  ", "Beth  ", 
    "Yong  ", "Celestina  ", "Paulita  ", "Laurence  ", "Sammy  ", 
    "Monte  ", "Mary  ", "Natalie  ", "Gilda  ", "Peggie  ", 
    "Robin  ", "Jerry  ", "Ester  ", "Dannie  ", "Rosalee  ", 
    "Mari  ", "Alona  ", "Petra  ", "Percy  ", "Heidi  ", "Charis  ", 
    "Sanjuana  ", "Elin  ", "Dottie  ", "Tawanna  ", "Sherie  ", 
    "Lera  ", "Lina  ", "Celestina  ", "Celestina  ", "Caryn  ", "Roscoe  ", 
    "Kimberley  ", "Linn  ", "Sanjuana  ", "Sanjuana  ", "Lynn  ", 
    "Natalie  ", "Charley  ", "Jenni  ", "Patti  ", "Yevette  ", 
    "Rebbecca  ", "Natalie  ", "Natalie  ", "Georgiann  "), ViewingType = c("Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Embedded Viewer", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand", 
    "Interactive Desktop On Demand", "Interactive Desktop On Demand"
    ), TimestampDate = structure(c(1505088000, 1505088000, 1505088000, 
    1505088000, 1505174400, 1505174400, 1505174400, 1505260800, 
    1505260800, 1505260800, 1505347200, 1505606400, 1505606400, 
    1505606400, 1505692800, 1505692800, 1505952000, 1505952000, 
    1505952000, 1505952000, 1505952000, 1505952000, 1506038400, 
    1506124800, 1506211200, 1506211200, 1506211200, 1506297600, 
    1506297600, 1506902400, 1506902400, 1506902400, 1506902400, 
    1506902400, 1507334400, 1507334400, 1507334400, 1507420800, 
    1507593600, 1507593600, 1507766400, 1507766400, 1507766400, 
    1508284800, 1508284800, 1508457600, 1508457600, 1508457600, 
    1508457600, 1508457600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("Module", 
"Timestamp", "SessionName", "MinutesDelivered", "UserName", "ViewingType", 
"TimestampDate"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: can you make a reproducible example with dput()?

Comment: Assuming you convert this to a data.table (e.g. `DT<-as.data.table(DF)`) you can use `DT[,.(Count=.N),by=.(UserName,SessionName,TimestampDate)]` to get the number of rows by UserName,SessionName,TimeStampDate

Comment: Thank you @digEmAll I had to do a bit of reading on data.table, the syntax can be very tricky, but I'm getting it, Thanks